# Portable hack to leak raw pointer from weak_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I have object structure which is made of `shared_ptr`s, plus `weak_ptr`s to avoid circularity. **Raw pointers are a no-go** as `boost::serialization` needs to restore shared and weak pointers when deserializing via object tracking as serialization time. Object lifetime patterns are complex (particle simulation) but entirely predictable. Whenever I use `weak_ptr::lock()`, I am sure the pointer is still valid. Typically, I use `lock().get()` as I only need the object for a very short time.

Now, `lock().get()` has performance implications, as it will increment shared count (in `lock()`), and then decrement it shortly afterwards (the temporary `shared_ptr` is destructed).

This [boost.devel post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/65332) from 2002 says that while `weak_ptr` was being developed, the functionality of accessing the raw pointer directly was considered (to be named `unsafe_get` or `leak`) but never made it to the actual implementation. Its absence forces programmer to use suboptimal interface under given conditions.

Now, the question is how to emulate the `unsafe_get`/`leak`, in another words, get the raw pointer from `weak_ptr`, invalid at the programmer's risk, only reading (not writing) data. I can imagine that some trickery like finding out the offset of the raw pointer inside `shared_ptr` or such would do the job.

I am using `boost::shared_ptr`, but the solution could work for c++11's `std::shared_ptr` as well.

Comment: Good question but it honestly sounds like raw pointers would be the better deal here. Manage the objects separately (e.g. pool all your particles in a container) and pass around weak pointers to those.

Comment: I think even if you are only using the object for a short time you should hold the `shared_ptr` while you are using it: `auto s = w.lock(); if (s) s->doSomething();` I think using `lock().get()` is bad practice and no faster. It is possible that the very action of using the pointer could actually trigger the last `shared_ptr` to die.

Comment: If you know the weak pointed to objects lifetime without a `.lock()` do not use a `weak_ptr`.  Have you proven this is a performance bottleneck as an aside?

Comment: @eudoxos Sorry for offtopic, but... How the heck your particles ever got managed with pointers? I'm sure you could solve all performance problems by removing all your too-way-smart-pointers and by iterating simply and stupidly through `std::vector` instead. "Weeks of coding can save you hours of designing" ;)

Comment: @Drop: the code is open-source, if you want to solve all my performance problems please head to [the repo](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~eudoxos/woo/trunk/files). I give you 1000€ for every 10% speedup without sacrifying functionality, flexibility, extensibility.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write some custom serialization/deserialization code that fixes up the raw pointers post-serialization, than to use `weak_ptr` just for the sake of serialization and then hack around its weaknesses?

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I am not able to do that; it would mean writing also another custom code for shared_ptr (object tracking) as both sides must be kept in sync. I don't think absence of pointer access is not weakness of weak_ptr, it is a missing piece in its interface.

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked for a portable hack.

A funny part of code found in [boost's weak_ptr.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.hpp) is:

```
template<class T> class weak_ptr
{
  ...

public:

  ...

// Tasteless as this may seem, making all members public allows member templates
// to work in the absence of member template friends. (Matthew Langston)

#ifndef BOOST_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATE_FRIENDS

private:

    template<class Y> friend class weak_ptr;
    template<class Y> friend class shared_ptr;

#endif

    element_type * px;            // contained pointer
    boost::detail::weak_count pn; // reference counter

};  // weak_ptr
```

Which means if you compile boost with the `BOOST_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATE_FRIENDS` option, you will publicly have access to the member `px` of weak_ptr which seems to be a raw pointer to the element type.

Comment: I’m not sure how future-proof this is … what’s Boost’s policy about breaking binary compatibility in future releases? Because if they allow it (very valid) then this hack unfortunately isn’t portable. And it won’t work with `std::weak_ptr` either.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well if it was future-proof it wouldn't be a hack. But at a given time this hack is as portable as the boost libraries are, it can only break when you upgrade your boost version, but as can any other normal feature from boost.

Comment: Another option could be to take advantage of the friendship: explicitly specialize a weak_ptr using a specially-designated type Y, and then access px: `template <> weak_ptr<WeakPtrAccessor> { /* friend of weak_ptr<T> */ };`.  The template friend is a generic access backdoor.

Comment: @Drax, well spotted, unfortunately I need it to work with stock (packaged) versions of boost under various linux distributions.

Comment: @eudoxos Then the solution proposed by NicholasM in the comments might be a good one.

Comment: @NicholasM: nice, could you perhaps post it as an answer, with a few lines example on how to do that? I like the idea.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you simply hold both a `weak_ptr` and a raw pointer and use the raw pointer directly as an optimization when you know it is safe to do so. You could wrap up the `weak_ptr` and associated raw pointer in a class that has an `unsafe_get` if you like.

Comment: A relevant note being that it's perfectly valid to store, use and pass around raw pointers and references even since C++11 so long as those pointers are understood not to "own" or manage the lifetime of the object - the rule for safety is that you must know that some "owner" (such as a `shared_ptr` to the same object) outlives them. Of course a `weak_ptr` doesn't own the object it references, so there are possible issues there if you can't be sure about the lifetime of that object - is it possible some other code could destruct the last `shared_ptr` to that `weak_ptr`-referenced object?

Comment: No doubt that's why there isn't an `unsafe_lock` in the standard. Using `lock().get()` (ie not keeping the `shared_ptr` as long as you're using the raw pointer) is pretty fragile too.

Comment: @Steve314: OT: I don't think it is the business of c++ to restrict one because of possible dangers. I agree it is not good to encourage dangerous practices, but not including something because it **could** be abused is a bit parenting.

Comment: @eudoxos - `lock().get()` is there even though it can be abused, and `unsafe_lock()` would only be an optimization of that with (I'd have thought) very few uses where the saving matters. I have only guesses about the motives, but it's hard to accuse C++ of being too protective - it's hardly lacking sharp tools.